# Surface Pro boots to UEFI only after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

After installing Ubuntu my Surface Pro will only boot into the UEFI firmware settings. I have re-installed the OS several times with the same result, I have also run "check disk for defects" and it comes back fine.  I ran boot-repair utility and it still hasn't corrected the problem, it said that it did but when I try to reboot as instructed it loads UEFI.

The only way that I can get my Surface to load the Ubuntu OS is to launch it via the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option, but I want it to be my primary (only OS) on this device, the Windows OS files have been overwritten at this point anyways.

Comment: Perhaps you need to disable secure boot.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: CelticWarrior, thanks, but that's not the issue, secure boot is disabled, you can not boot to USB with the Surface pro unless it is. ..

Comment: @oldfred this is the link to the boot-repair link: http://paste2.org/bBHJjnM7  I am really hoping that someone can help me out with this, I have read about quite a few similar issues, however none of the solutions have helped and at the moment the only way that I can use my device is via a live session:-(

Comment: Another Surface Pro.  You have multiple Windows UEFI boot entries. And you may need only one UEFI boot entry that says "Windows Boot Manager" but actually boots using shimx64.efi. This was my d1: but renumbered to IV. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Another Surface Pro http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309963&p=13424798#post13424798  To delete UEFI entries: `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` see `man efibootmgr` for details.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Surface Pro, I wanted to dual boot with Kubuntu and Windows 8.1. After installing Kubuntu I couldn't boot into Kubuntu from the HDD - only from the live USB.

I tried a lot of things including boot-repair. Eventually I gave in and tried rEFInd which I saw mentioned somewhere online. I booted into the Kubuntu live usb and installed rEFInd after mounting `/dev/sda2` as `/boot/efi`. As it's installing it loads onto the `/boot/efi` partition. You'll have to click "ok" at one point in the install. I rebooted and was left with a bunch of boot options! Looks good! I chose one of the first ubuntu partitons and it booted!

The instructions that worked for me:

First boot into a live USB session

```
sudo mkdir -p /boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/sdXN /boot/efi
```

where sdXN is your efi partition, eg sda2 in my case. If you don’t know the values of X and N for your system then fire up gparted and look for the partition with a boot flag.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install refind
```

then reboot.

edit: found the original answer that this is based on and fixed up a mistake in my code: [How Can I Get GRUB to Work After Restoring Deleted EFI Partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524059/how-can-i-get-grub-to-work-after-restoring-deleted-efi-partition)